# Tikz : Place coordinate (or node) on a segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I need to draw in line in intersection with another one like this :

[image]

I was thinking about using [near start] and use nodes :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[label=above:A] (A) at (0,1) {$\bullet$};
        \node[label=above:B] (B) at (1,0) {$\bullet$};
        \node[label=above:C] (C) at (1,1) {$\bullet$};
        
        \draw (A) -- (B) node[near start=1cm, below] {D} node[near start=1cm] {$\bullet$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with coordinates, which is cleaner :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
        \draw (A) node[above] {A} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
        \draw (B) node[above] {B} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
        \draw (C) node[above] {C} node {$\bullet$};
        
        \draw (A) -- (B) node[near start=1cm, below] {D} node[near start=1cm] {$\bullet$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have placed the label D, but I can use it anymore to draw the line (DC).
Someone has an idea ?

**Edit :** [near start] is like [pos=0.25], i think it's a better way to place the node

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Simply place a coordinate at the desired position and add the bullet label separately.
Then connect the coordinates for `C` and `D`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
        \draw (A) node[above] {A} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
        \draw (B) node[above] {B} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
        \draw (C) node[above] {C} node {$\bullet$};
        
        \draw (A) -- (B) node[near start=1cm, below] {D} coordinate[near start=1cm] (D); 
        \node at (D) {$\bullet$};
        \draw (D) -- (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `calc` library, you can control the position of the node `D`, like,

```
\coordinate (D) at ($(A)!0.25!(B)$);
```

Then draw from `C`  to `D`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
        \draw (A) node[above] {A} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
        \draw (B) node[above] {B} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
        \draw (C) node[above] {C} node {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate (D) at ($(A)!0.25!(B)$);
        \draw (D) node[below] {D} node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (A) -- (B) ;
        \draw (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a more compact syntax

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    point/.style={circle, draw, thin, fill=blue, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
    text=blue, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, label distance=-2pt]
    \draw[thick] (0,1) node[point, label=A]{} -- node[near start, point, label=D] (d) {} (1,0) node[point, label=B] {};
    \draw[thick] (d) -- (1,1) node[point, label=C]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]